# symfony 1.4 Embed a subform in another subform with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony-1.4

I know symfony 1.4 Form system is not the best and is causing many people a lot of troubles, but I need to get finished with this task and I need help.

I need to embed a subform into a subform that is embedded in a main form, and do it via Ajax.

Basically I have aForm, bForm and cForm and aForm embeds bForm and bForm can have one or more cForm.

When I embed them normally from the configure() function of each form it works. But when I try to use Ajax to embed multiple cForms into bForm I fail to bind them.

This is the version that works. Everything is embedding ok and validating ok.

```
class BookingForm extends BaseBookingForm
{
  public function configure()
  {     
      $this->embedRelation('Journey as journey');
  }
}

[...]

class JourneyForm extends BaseJourneyForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
      $pickup_form = new JourneyItineraryForm();
      $this->embedForm('pickup_form', $pickup_form);

  }
} 

[...]

class JourneyItineraryForm extends BaseJourneyItineraryForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
  }
}

[...]
```

Now, if I try to embed JourneyItineraryForm via ajax I managed to get the widgets displayed in the template but it fails to bind them. It says to me **Unexpected extra form field named "waypoint".**

View code below:

```
class JourneyForm extends BaseJourneyForm
{
      public function configure()
      {
          $waypoint_form = new JourneyItineraryForm();
          $this->embedForm('waypoint', $waypoint_form);

      }

      public function addNewWaypoint($number)
      {
       /*
       * Called from actions.class.php after an ajax request
       */

       $new_waypoints = new BaseForm();

       for($i=0; $i <= $number; $i+=1)
       {
         $waypoint = new JourneyItinerary();
         $waypoint_form = new JourneyItineraryForm($waypoint);
         $new_waypoints->embedForm($i,$waypoint_form);
       }

      $this->embedForm('waypoint', $new_waypoints);
      }

    public function bind(array $taintedValues = null, array $taintedFiles = null)
    {

      $new_occurrences = new BaseForm();
      foreach($taintedValues['waypoint'] as $key => $new_occurrence)
      {
        $occurrence = new JourneyItinerary();      
        $occurrence_form = new JourneyItineraryForm($occurrence);
        $new_occurrences->embedForm($key,$occurrence_form);
      }

      $this->embedForm('waypoint',$new_occurrences);

      parent::bind($taintedValues, $taintedFiles);
    }
 }
```

I my template I manage to display the waypoints widgets like

```
$form['journey']['waypoint'][0]['field_name']->renderRow();
```

I also tried to overwrite the bind method from BookingForm but I don't know if I did it correctly:

```
public function bind(array $taintedValues = null, array $taintedFiles = null)
{   
    $new_occurrences = new sfForm();
    foreach($taintedValues['journey']['waypoint'] as $key => $new_occurrence)
    {
      $occurrence = new JourneyItinerary();      
      $occurrence_form = new JourneyItineraryForm($occurrence);

      $new_occurrences->embedForm($key,$occurrence_form);
    }

    $this->embedForm('journey',$new_occurrences);

    parent::bind($taintedValues, $taintedFiles);
}
```

I followed this tutorial:
http://tech.cibul.net/embedded-forms-with-symfony-1-4-and-jquery/
and also read the official documentation http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms

Any help is highly appreciated :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin [ahDoctrineEasyEmbeddedRelationsPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/ahDoctrineEasyEmbeddedRelationsPlugin), it is simple and fast. But you can not make embed in embed, but in you case you have in one form 2 embed form.